Why in the following functions do char* and void* need the same object representation and alignment requirements?
The answers to the questions raised yesterday have raised new doubts for me.
There is such a sentence in the official C99 rationale document:
A pointer to void must have the same representation and alignment as a pointer to char; the intent of this rule is to allow existing programs that call library functions such as memcpy and free to continue to work.
I have learned that the official C99 rationale document speaks to the intent and historical context of that provision. It observes that types void and void * were added in C89. Before then, it was conventional to use type char * in the pointer-to-anything role that void * now specifically serves, and standard library functions (among many others) were written accordingly.
And another piece of possibly useful information that I have learned is that in the old-style K&R style of function declarations, there are no function prototypes.
There are no automatic conversions for pointer values passed to a function without an in-scope prototype.
I saw in C89 that memcpy already has the function prototype void *memcpy (void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
before C89, char* was used as the generic pointer type, so No matter in what way and whether it was in the past or now,, any type can be a argument of memcpy and memcpy can be called normally. After C89, void* is used as the generic pointer type and memcpy has a function prototype. Now any type can also be an argument of memcpy(The type of the argument will be converted to the type of the parameter) and it can also be called normally. I can't see why void* needs to have the same representation and alignment requirements as char*.
In other words, even if char* and void* do not have the same object representation and alignment requirements, whether in the past or now, I cannot find any place where calling memcpy might violate the standard.
Then what does the sentence mentioned above mean? Can anyone come to save me?
Thank you for you reading.

Is your doubt the motivation behind the standard being the way it is?  I'm not a language lawyer, but follow this logic: memory addresses (i.e. pointers of the type char* or void*) point to a single byte in memory, which is what a char is.  Coincidentally, pointers to arrays work the same way (in that, it is a memory address to the first byte of the first element in the array) which is why strings can be represented as both char* and char[], and why pointer degradation exists.

Given this lineage, why would you expect it to work any differently now?  Stated another way, is there really any benefit to changing the standard so that void pointers no longer have the same semantics as char pointers?

In any case, your primary objection seems to be that you can't find any examples where memcopy is called with char pointers

Old code would sometimes have things like: struct Something *dst = …; struct Something *src = …; and then memcpy((char *)dst, (char *)src, sizeof(struct Something); — but nowadays, the conversion from struct Something * to char * is likely to elicit a warning about converting between incompatible pointer types.  Removing the (char *) casts fixes that problem.  (I get to remove a lot of superfluous casts in the antique code line I work on.  They were probably necessary in the mid-90s — though I'm not always convinced of that.  They're no longer necessary.)

Traditionally, a program could be constructed by using one or more compilers to convert source code files into object code files and then, either immediately or at some later time those object files could be combined to produce a finished program.
The intention of the Standard here was to ensure that object files which were produced by tools that had no concept of what a void* might be should be usable with code that was written to use void* instead of char* when doing so would make sense, rather than requiring that people have separate versions of a function which accept char* (for compatibility with old code) and void*.
Note that the Standard was viewed rather differently in 1990 than in 2024.  Back then, compiler writers' priority was compatibility with code written for other implementations, and compiler writers could look to precedent when deciding how to handle existing constructs.  In describing the new new void* feature for which on some platforms there might not be any established precedent, the authors of the Standard wanted to guide compiler writers use precedents applicable to the existing char* type.


In other words, even if char* and void* do not have the same object representation and alignment requirements, whether in the past or now, I cannot find any place where calling memcpy might violate the standard.

I already provide exactly such an example in my answer to your previous question.  Recapitulating it here:
char *memcpy();

int example() {
    char a = 'A';
    char a2;
    memcpy(&a2, &a, sizeof a);
    putchar(a2);
}

That is a valid, complete translation unit in K&R C.  Note that it does not include any headers: it relies on its own declaration of memcpy(), and it calls putchar() without a prior declaration.
It is almost a valid, complete translation unit in C89 as well, but it stumbles over the fact that in C89, memcpy() is declared to return void * which, interchangeability aside, is not "compatible" with char * as the spec defines that term.  It would be completely valid C89 if it declared the return type of memcpy as void *, and note that in this case, it still would not provide a prototype for either memcpy or putchar.
The intention of the C89 committee was that implementors of that version of the language should provide that an object resulting from compiling that code with their compiler should be binary compatible with result of compiling it with their older K&R compiler for the same target machine, and that it should also work correctly with their C89 standard library's memcpy().
There are two main issues with that:

The char * return type is not compatible with the void * return type of C89's memcpy.  As a result, the C89 language spec does not define the behavior of the memcpy() call in that code.  The committee seems to have been hoping -- reasonably, IMO -- that implementations would choose to define the resulting behavior in the natural, compatible way.  That char * and void * were specified to have the same representation and alignment requirements facilitated such implementation behavior. Or alternatively, providing such behavior very nearly required the two types to have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.

The only in-scope declaration of memcpy() in that code does not provide a prototype.  In this case, the arguments to a call to that function are subject (only) to the default argument promotions, which do nothing to pointers.  The first two arguments to that call have type char *, and it is reasonable to suppose that their values will be passed to memcpy as representations of that type.
For its part, C89 memcpy() expects to receive values of type void * for its first two arguments.  C does not define any way for it to determine these values' types from the values themselves, so the most natural behavior is for that function simply to interpret the values passed as if they were of the expected type. How is it going to work if void * and char * have different representations?  In fact, C89 refuses to define the behavior of the call on account of incompatible argument types, too. That seems to have been a defect, however, because C99 adds an explicit exception for this case to the argument / parameter type compatibility rules.



Then what does the sentence mentioned above mean?

I don't think I can rewrite the sentence from the rationale any more clearly.  Requiring char * and void * to have the same representation and alignment requirements ensures that an object representation of one type can be reinterpreted as an equivalent object representation of the other type.  This at minimum facilitates binary compatibility and some degree of source compatibility across function call interfaces.  It may be stronger than is absolutely necessary for that purpose, for some implementations, but I don't think it's too strong as a rule sufficient for all implementations.

"so the most natural behavior is for that function simply to interpret the values passed as if they were of the expected type."  Does this mean that even if there is a function prototype, it is not necessary to convert the arguments  of type char* to the  parameters of type void*?

@user24723440, when there is an in-scope prototype, there is a conversion, at least notionally, because the spec says there is one.  But I can't imagine a case where it would be more than notional.  This is much like converting 0u to 0.  There is a conversion, but it doesn't change any of the bytes of the value.

On ancient hardware that wasn't byte-addressed, a char* might have been larger than an int*. The extra size was used for "part-word" info, to select a single character out of a multi-character word.
The rule is just that on such machines, a void* must also have this extra space, so it can store a char*.
On all other types of hardware, the rule means nothing.

You need char* and void* to have identical representations to preserve ABI compatibility. The rule wouldn't be needed if everything could be recompiled.

In addition to what has already been said, there's the requirements from C11 6.3.2.3:

A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

This requirement makes it mighty inconvenient to implement any object pointer with a different format than void*, because if they have different formats, then in order to fulfill the above requirement, the compiler must add/remove some extra bytes to the pointer representation whenever converting to/from void*.
That has to my knowledge never happened even on exotic systems where things like extended addressing works. It would be too cumbersome to implement, so all such known implementation have instead chosen to rely on non-standard extensions using keywords near and far, where one is compatible with the default pointer model and one is not. This was the case both back in MS DOS as well as on various 8/16 bit microcontrollers.
That is, rather than doing something strange and dangerous like:
char* p = near_address; 
void* vp = p;  // magically and silently convert to a larger address internally
char* p2 = vp; // magically and silently convert back

Compilers chose to implement non-standard near/far pointer qualifiers:
// assuming near addresses are the default, we don't need to use near keyword explicitly
char* p = near_address; 
void* far vp = (void* far) p;
char* p2 = (char*) vp;

If you don't use the casts then you'll get a diagnostic, since the two pointer types are not compatible - near/far work pretty much like standard type qualifiers (const/volatile).
(Some compilers for von Neumann architectures also allow near/far for functions, in case they allow code to be executed in different address spaces.)

Furthermore we have another requirement from 6.3.2.3:

When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

A low-level language needs this feature for hardware-related programming and serialization/deserialization purposes. Therefore character pointers cannot have alignment requirements and if they didn't but void* did, that would make pointer conversions strange and risky.
In the general pointer conversion scenario we have:

A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

Which means that something like int* p = (double*)&x; is allowed to trap during the conversion/assignment itself and not just when the pointer is de-referenced. (In practice some MMU might disallow certain address formats for data addresses and throw a hardware exception - not too uncommon.) If char* and void* had different alignment requirements, we'd have the same problem there.
